# PyFPDF can't add page while specifying the size

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, fpdf

on pyfpdf documentation it is said that it is possible to specify a format while adding a page (fpdf.add_page(orientation = '', format = '', same = False)) but it gives me an error when specifying a format.

error:

> pdf.add_page(format = (1000,100)) TypeError: add_page() got an
>   unexpected keyword argument 'format'

i've installed pyfpdf via pip install and setup.py install but it doesnt work in both ways

how can i solve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the exact error that you are getting. Saying that you are getting an error without including it isn't helpful and we can't possibly know or even guess what the problem might be.

Comment: @Dave thanks i've added the specific error. is it more clear now?

Comment: The values you are passing to `add_page` look completely wrong according to [the documentation](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/add_page/index.html). The first parameter must be `P` or `L` and the 2nd one a size or a tuple as you are trying to do. From the looks of it your call should be `pdf.add_page('P',(1000,100));`.

Comment: @Dave (i had already tryed this) this command returns this error: pdf.add_page('P', (1000,100)) TypeError: add_page() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you checked the documentation from python using help() you can find out that add_page() only accept one argument.

> add_page(self, orientation='')
> Start a new page

It seems inconsistent with the documentation they wrote on [pypdf](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/add_page/index.html). But this happen if you install fpdf via pip. Try install it from [github master](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf) branch. This should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that two packages of pypdf exist, `fpdf` and `fpdf2`. They both use `from fpdf import FPDF`, but only fpdf2 has also a `format=` keyword in the `add_page()` method.

So you need to install the `fpdf2` package.